How do I remove the flicker on Stripe Pricing Tables
I am using the Stripe Pricing Table, but it flickers into view. How can I stop the flicker and remove the animation?

And this is my React page:
    import { Shell } from '@/components/shells/shell'
    import { getSessionUser } from '@/lib/db/users'
    import Stripe from '@/lib/stripe'
    
    export default async function Page() {
      const user = await getSessionUser()
      return (
        <Shell>
          <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-6xl">
            <script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `<stripe-pricing-table \
                  pricing-table-id="${Stripe.pricingTableID}" \
                  publishable-key="${Stripe.publishableKey}" \
                  client-reference-id="${user.id}" \
                ></stripe-pricing-table>`,
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </Shell>
      )
    }


Based on the information on Stripe doc. I'm afraid that there's no option to remove the loading animation for a pricing table.

You should try the following:
'use client';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const PricingPage = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
     const script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js';
     script.async = true;
     
     // Add script to document
     document.body.appendChild(script);
     
     // Cleanup function
     return () => {
       document.body.removeChild(script);
     };
   }, []); // Empty dependency array means this runs once on mount
  return (
     <stripe-pricing-table 
       pricing-table-id="YOUR_TABLE_ID"
       publishable-key="YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"
     />
   );
};
export default PricingPage;

(source)

This is the exact same thing as what I have. When you tested it, did yours flicker?
